# How to handle recursive objects with JMS Serializer

Tags: php, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

I am trying to serialize and deserialize a Doctrine object graph.

The structure is pretty complex, but this example sums up my problem:

There is a `Company` entity with a OneToMany relationship to `Employee`.
The `Employee` entity has a ManyToOne relationship with the `Company`.

This is serialized as follows:

```
{
    "company": {
        "name": "MegaCorp",
        "employees": [{
            "name": "John Doe",
            "company": null
        }]
    }
}
```

So it `null`s the reference to the `Employee`'s parent `Company`. For serialization this is ok.
But now when I deserialize this json, I get a `null` `Company` in the `Employee` object. What I want (and expect) is to get a correct reference to the parent `Company`.

Is this possible using JMS serializer and if so, how can it be done?
If it is not possible, what could be a good workaround? Remember that it is a large graph, I don't want to do it manually.

Comment: Instead of null'ing the reference, use it's ID. Basically, you want a proxy instead of the real object. I don't know if JMS supports this out of the box.

Comment: That would be a possible solution, but indeed the question is: Does JMS support something like that?

Comment: I know it has `@preSerialize` and `@postSerialize` hooks. So it's doable.

Comment: Yeah, I am looking into that now, but I feel like this is not an uncommon use case and as such expect it to be supported by JMS by default.

Comment: Have you already tried [`MaxDepth()`](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/cookbook/exclusion_strategies)?

Comment: @kingkero: How would that help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, when deserializing, there is no way for the serializer to know whether the objects are identical or actually the same object. Even if you could nest them recursively.

But, you can get the desired result when combining the `@Accessor` annotation with some business logic. So going off of your example:

```
class Company {
    /**
     * @Accessor(setter="addEmployees")
     */
    private $employees;

    public function addEmployee(Employee $employee)
    {
        if (!$this->employees->contains($employee)) {
            $this->employees[] = $employee;
            $employee->setCompany($this);
        }
    }

    public function addEmployees($employees)
    {
        foreach ($employees as $employee) {
            $this->addEmployee($employee);
        }
    }
}

class Employee {
    /**
     * @Accessor(setter="setCompany")
     */
    private $company;

    public setCompany(Company $company = null)
    {
        $this->company = $company;

        if ($company) {
            $company->addEmployee($this);
        }
    }
}
```

I think this is a more natural approach than using `@PostDeserialize` as you probably already have some of these methods in your code. Also, it ensures the contract in both ways, so if you were to start from `Employee` you'd get the same result.

Comment: This is actually a slightly better implementation than my current solution involving a PostDeserialize hook on the Company. The basic idea is the same though.

Comment: Yeah. I'm afraid there is no getting around that... As I said, there is no way for the serializer to pick up any relations apart from those enforced by the json structure on itself.

Comment: I think you are right. I have implemented it now using the @Accessor method, works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What's about set the reference manually when you have deserialize the object? Something like this:

```
class Company { 

    ....

    @PostDeserialize
    public function setReferences()
    {
        foreach( $this->employees as $employee ){
            $employee->setCompany( $this );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is a good practice to keep as simple as possible your JSON entities! If you have to deal with this kind of issues, is the moment to rethink your data model!

In addition, did you think about use HATEOAS (Hypermedia as the Engine of Application State) is a principle that hypertext links should be used to create a better navigation through the API. Looks like this:

```
{
  "id": 711,
  "manufacturer": "bmw",
  "model": "X5",
  "seats": 5,
  "drivers": [
   {
    "id": "23",
    "name": "Stefan Jauker",
    "links": [
     {
     "rel": "self",
     "href": "/api/v1/drivers/23"
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is a legacy application I had to interface with. Otherwise, I couldn't agree more!

Comment: Got it... So, the client who reads this JSON must be aware of this cyclic dependencies and set the references on decode the JSON.